# Scroll view scroll Direction

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I wrote a piece of code for scroll view auto scroll today which probably has a mind of it's own. :-)

```
- (void)animateScrollView
{
    CGPoint point1 = CGPointMake(self.collectionView.contentSize.width + self.collectionView.contentInset.left, 0.0f);
    [self.collectionView setContentOffset:point1 animated:NO];

    CGPoint point2 = CGPointMake(self.collectionView.contentInset.left, 0.0f);
    [self.collectionView setContentOffset:point2 animated:YES];
}
```

point1 = (4000,0) and point2 = (0,0)

It scrolls from L -> R. Shouldn't it be scrolling from R -> L?

Comment: does orientation of the phone impact this? (portrait vs landscape)

Comment: I am testing in portrait only mode.